# How to load camera scanner?

Tags: swift, xcode, file, pdf

I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <VNDocumentCameraViewController_InProcess: 0x109e216c0> on <[myapp]> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

when calling my function:

```
public func scanDocument() {

        let scannerViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
        scannerViewController.delegate = self
        present(scannerViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Where are you calling `scanDocument()` from?

Comment: @nanibir I am calling scanDocument from another class, via a button. When I click the button I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call `present` from a view controller which is already in the view hierarchy. So make sure the view controller you have the `scanDocument` function in is already presented / pushed / made visible first.